# Scroll CSS Floats instead of breaking

Tags: css, css-float

I'm creating a series of columns all floated left against eachother. I'd like to make it so that when the columns are larger than their container a horizontal scrollbar appears instead of the columns dropping down. Here's what I have...

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="col1" class="col">Column One</div>
    <div id="col2" class="col">Column Two</div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

With the css:

```
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
#container { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.col { float: left; width: 250px; height: 100%; }
```

I would ideally like to have the scrollbar on the page/body level since the page is nothing but the columns.

Comment: Bear in mind you've misspelled "container" in your CSS but not in your HTML!

Comment: My original code was correct. Just typed in here wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work with this CSS :

```
#container { width: 100%; overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap; }
.col { display: inline-block; width: 250px; }
```

**Caution : display-block not working on IE <= 7**

An other solution is to use two containers and fix the width of the second with the sum of columns width :

```
#container1 { width: 100%; overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap; }
#container2 { width: 1250px; }
.col { float:left; width: 250px; }

<div id="container1">
  <div id="container2">
    <div class="col">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col">Column 4</div>
    <div class="col">Column 5</div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the scrollbar on the body, just remove overflow:auto on #container and #container1

Comment: inline-block instead of float and nowrap on the container worked beautifully. No worries on IE<=7, this is a pretty controlled application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

put the width out of container and body. That should resolve the problem.

Comment: Doesn't work, still drops the floats when I resize the window.